# Enforcing business rules in entity framework core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, transactions, entity-framework-core

Let's assume that I have a controller's action which does the following:

1. checks if there is a calendar slot at a particular time
2. checks if there are no appointments already booked that overlap with that slot
3. if both conditions are satisfied it creates a new appointment at the given time

The trivial implementation presents multiple problems:

- what if the calendar slot fetched in 1 is removed before step 3?
- what if another appointment is booked after step 2 but before step 3?

The solution to these problems seems to be using the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level. The problem is that everybody seems to consider this transaction isolation level to be extremely dangerous as it may lead to deadlocks.

Given the following trivial solution:

```
public class AController
{
    // ...
    public async Task Fn(..., CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var calendarSlotExists = dbContext.Slots.Where(...).AnyAsync(cancellationToken);
        var appointmentsAreOverlapping = dbContext.Appointments.Where(...).AnyAsync(cancellationToken);
        if (calendarSlotExists && !appointmentsAreOverlapping)
            dbContext.Appointments.Add(...);
        dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

what would be the best way to always prevent concurrency problems and how should I handle eventual deadlocks?

Comment: How quickly are these events coming in and could you handle them in a queue and process them one at a time? Sometimes the best way to solve concurrency problems is to get rid of concurrency. This also would be a good way to ensure first come, first served for booking.

Comment: @Shoe do you really need `SERIALIZABLE` here? Isn't `REPEATABLE READ` enough?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The consensus seems to be that phantom reads can happen in REPEATABLE READ, and given that it's defined as "a phantom read occurs when, in the course of a transaction, new rows are added or removed by another transaction to the records being read." it seems to me that if the slot is removed after step 1 but before step 3 you still have an inconsistent state. No?

Comment: Another option is to allow users to make overlapping appointments and notify them when this happens (as in Outlook).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database integrity check is your best friend

Based on your description your appointments are based on slots. This made the problem a lot simpler since you can efficiently define a unique constraint for `SlotId` on the `Appointments` table. And then you would need a foreign key for `Appointments.SlotId` references `Slot.Id`

> what if the calendar slot fetched in 1 is removed before step 3?

DB would throw foreign key violation exception

> what if another appointment is booked after step 2 but before step 3?

DB would throw duplicated key exception

What you need to do next is to catch those two exceptions and redirect user back to the booking page. Reload data from DB again and check for any invalid entries, notify the user to make modification and try again.

For the deadlock part it really depends on your table structure. The way you access data, the way you index them, and DB's query plan. Theres no definitive answer to that.

Comment: Appointments don't reference the slot id because there may be appointments without a slot and there are slots that are overlapping each other, which would mean that a slot goes from 12:30 to 13:30 and another may be available from 12:00 to 13:00. Can you expand on what are the best practices for situations when a trivial database integrity constraint is not possible?

Comment: @Shoe can you share table schema with example use case + edge cases? Also whats the server load and how many appointments are you expecting to have in the DB? One option would be to grab an exclusive table lock but thats like turning your application into a single thread model which is not recommended. Integrity check would still be my first attempt.

Comment: The problem is just an example to ask how about how to enforce non trivial (trivially solvable via database integrity constraints) business rules.

Comment: @Shoe there exists non-trivial integrity rules that you can apply. Such as applying unique/foreign key constrain on indexed (materialized) view. Trying to do this at application level is basically trying to reinvent Db integrity check. If performance is not an issue then exclusive table lock is a quick way out. As i mentioned in previous comment its all case by case. Completely depends on your use case, table schema AND your DB engine. (query that runs perfectly on MySql might deadlock on SqlServer. All depends on how your DB handles lock order and lock strategy)

Comment: I'm not completely sold on the idea that you can always use DB constraints alone for any integrity constraint. But I guess this specific problem can be solved through those. I was looking for an answer to those other cases though. Bounty is about to expire so I guess you win.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need a pessimistic concurrency approach to manage your task. Unfortunately, it is not supported in Entity Framework Core.

Alternatively, you can use an static ConcurrentDictionary or implement your own ConcurrentHashSet to keep safe from  multiple requests and avoid another Appointment could be booked after step 2 but before step 3.

About calendar slot fetched in 1 being removed before step 3 problem, I think that having a foreign key relation between Appointment and Slot to check the database integrity at SaveChanges, or having the ConcurrentDictionary/ConcurrentHashSet Public and checking it from another actions (remove Slots, etc) before perform them, are good options to solve it.

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> operations = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();

    public async Task<IActionResult> AControllerAction()
    {
        int? calendarSlotId = 1; //await dbContext.Slots.FirstOrDefaultAsync(..., cancellationToken))?.Id;

        try
        {
            if (calendarSlotId != null && operations.TryAdd(calendarSlotId.Value, null))
            {
                bool appointmentsAreOverlapping = false; //await dbContext.Slots.Where(...).AnyAsync(cancellationToken);

                if (!appointmentsAreOverlapping)
                {
                    //dbContext.Appointments.Add(...);
                    //await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

                    return ...; //All done!
                }

                return ...; //Appointments are overlapping
            }

            return ...; //There is no slot or slot is being used
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ...; //ex exception (DB exceptions, etc)
        }
        finally
        {
            if (calendarSlotId != null)
            {
                operations.TryRemove(calendarSlotId.Value, out object obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, in high availability scenarios, it is advisable to trade off immediate consistency (obtained with transactions) for eventual consistency (obtained with workflows/sagas).

In your example, you could consider an approach which uses an intermediate state for storing a "pending" appointment, followed by a new check for its consistency.

```
public async Task Fn(..., CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // suppose "appointment" is our entity, we will store it as "pending" using
    // PendingUntil property (which is Nullable<DateTimeOffset>).
    // an appointment is in "pending" state if the PendingUntil property is set
    // (not null), and its value is >= UtcNow
    var utcNow = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    appointment.PendingUntil = utcNow.AddSeconds(5);

    // we will then use this property to find out if there are other pending appointments

    var calendarSlotExists = await dbContext.Slots.Where(...).AnyAsync(cancellationToken);
    var appointmentsAreOverlapping = await dbContext.Appointments
                                                    .Where(...)
                                                    .Where(a => a.PendingUntil == null || 
                                                                a.PendingUntil >= now)
                                                    .AnyAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (calendarSlotExists && !appointmentsAreOverlapping)
        dbContext.Appointments.Add(appointment);
    else
        return BadRequest(); // whatever you what to return

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken); // save the pending appointment

    // now check if the pending appointment is still valid

    var calendarSlotStillExists = await dbContext.Slots.Where(...).AnyAsync(cancellationToken); // same query as before

    // a note on the calendar slot existance: you should of course negate any
    // slot deletion for (pending or not) appointments.

    // we will then check if there is any other appointment in pending state that was
    // stored inside the database "before" this one.
    // this query is up to you, below you'll find just an example

    var overlappingAppointments = await dbContext.Appointments.Where(...)
                                                 .Where(a => a.Id != appointment.Id &&
                                                             a.PendingUntil == null || 
                                                             a.PendingUntil >= now)
                                                 .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

    // we are checking if other appointments (pending or not) have been written to the DB
    // of course we need to exclude the appointment we just added

    if (!calendarSlotStillExists || overlappingAppointments.Any(a => a.PendingUntil == null || a.PendingUntil < appointment.PendingUntil)
    {
        // concurrency check failed
        // this means that another appointment was added after our first check, but before our appointment.
        // we have to remove the our appointment
        dbContext.Appointments.Remove(appointment);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken); // restore DB
        return BadRequest(); // same response as before
    }

    // ok, we can remove the pending state
    appointment.PendingUntil = null;

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken); // insert completed
    return Ok();
}
```

This, of course, will double hits to the database, but will avoid transactions (with deadlocks and locking latency) completely.

You just need to evaluate which aspect is more important for you: scalability or immediate consistency.